# How to recover InnoDB after DB failure?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I was trying to install the mysqlgovernor, and in the end I got this mess, and now all my websites are down.

```
root@panel [~]# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-03-06 06:35:31 CET; 5s ago
  Process: 6244 ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6243 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6205 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6179 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6243 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service

Mar 06 06:35:28 panel.uhlhosting.ch mariadb-prepare-db-dir[6205]: touch: cannot touch 'panel.uhlhosting.ch.err': Permission denied
Mar 06 06:35:28 panel.uhlhosting.ch mariadb-prepare-db-dir[6205]: chown: cannot access 'panel.uhlhosting.ch.err': No such file or directory
Mar 06 06:35:28 panel.uhlhosting.ch mariadb-prepare-db-dir[6205]: chmod: cannot access 'panel.uhlhosting.ch.err': No such file or directory
Mar 06 06:35:29 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld_safe[6243]: 160306 06:35:29 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/panel.uhlhosting.ch.err'.
Mar 06 06:35:29 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld_safe[6243]: 160306 06:35:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Mar 06 06:35:30 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld_safe[6243]: 160306 06:35:30 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/panel.uhlhosting.ch.pid ended
Mar 06 06:35:31 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 06 06:35:31 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Mar 06 06:35:31 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Mar 06 06:35:31 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
root@panel [~]#
```

Here is my Error list:

> InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140010623854336 in file buf0buf.cc line 2850

Here is the working MariaDB after reinstall, and disabling the InnoDB db's yet we do not want to be without them.

```
root@panel [~]# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-03-06 10:16:12 CET; 29min ago
 Main PID: 16551 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─16551 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128996632704 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.12-MariaDB) starting as process 16551 ...
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128996632704 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128996632704 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128996632704 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128995883776 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1286: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: 2016-03-06 10:16:12 140128996632704 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch mysqld[16551]: Version: '10.1.12-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
Mar 06 10:16:12 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Mar 06 10:16:54 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
Mar 06 10:17:00 panel.uhlhosting.ch systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
```

[Server.err](https://gist.github.com/highacid/271137e25af45d1419af)

[my.cnf file](https://gist.github.com/highacid/d35f6794bc102cf58565)

Comment: Have you taken a complete backup of the databases and server? If you are experimenting to fix this, there's a chance that something you do will make matters worse - so take a snapshot as the first thing you do.

Comment: @halfer yes a backup was in place.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @RickJames 24 GB ram.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the first three lines of the error-log:
MariaDB has no permission to write on the directory where panel.uhlhosting.ch.err is located

You can fix this by changing the owner/group of this directory to mysql:mysql by `chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/directory/` if it's on linux.

Comment: This is not only a simple permission issue, i tried many ways and nothing worked to recover my DB;s right now all DB;s are in MyISAM, if I enable InnoDB the mariadb dies again.

Comment: They must be in MyISAM while this ist the default format tabels are stored in, when innodb is disabled or unknown like it is written in your error-log. I think you should stop replication  and first fix the issue with innodb.

Comment: I agree, tell me how to fix the issue :) This is what I try to get here some insights I am not a MySQL guru.

Comment: so your're working definitly on the wrong place ;). You can get innodb tables from myisam-tables by changing the storage engine in sql: `alter table mytable engine=innodb;` Please disbale replication first by editing your my.cnf and restart it with enabled innodb.

Comment: You think you could help me recover this? I would be able to pay for your time.

Comment: Maybe I can, but  i'm engaged... But have a look on some facts: If this is a new slave you're setting up, then start again. Is the replication Master a MySQL or a MariaDB system? If they are different, it won't work since MariaDB 10.x isn't the same to MySQL . It also will not work if you replicate a MariaDB-Version before 10.x (same reason). If I should add perhaps some more tipps, please edit your main post and show you my.cnf

Comment: My config is in the post already on bottom links. I am not using any replication yet, from this day on once I solve the issue will start using replication too.

Comment: The original config file is this one: https://gist.github.com/highacid/163c596ad1f8e066e68f

Comment: The issue `160306 06:45:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/panel.uhlhosting.ch.pid ended
160306 06:50:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql` isn't solved, it happens on every startup, I read in the errror-log. Is another DB running on the same hardware?

Comment: There should be only one mysql instance with more dbs for each cpanel user.